# REPLACE/REMOVE similar substrings from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to remove all the `\trxxx` substrings from following test string?

```
blabla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680blabla
```

To get `blabla-blabla`?

I've tried regex, but I failed:

```
select REPLACE('blabla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680blabla', '\tr[0-9]+', '')
```

Comment: Your desired result is not clear

Comment: Thanks, is it better?

Comment: Sql server supports only very small portion of regex, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: @gaffcz Much better

Comment: If you have to stick with the stock product, the other comments here say it all.  But if you are allowed to use CLR functions in your org, they can really help in these use cases.  See https://naturalselectiondba.wordpress.com/2016/02/06/sql-server-clr-functions-using-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server lacks Regex. You can use CLR integration (preferred if you have millions of records) or use recursive query. Example of recursive query with some test cases below:

```
WITH TestCases AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('blabla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680blabla'),
    ('\tr23SomeText\tr1'),
    ('bla99bla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680rock'),
    (''),
    (NULL)) T(Expr)
), Cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 R, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Expr) Rec, CONVERT(varchar(MAX), Expr) Expr
    FROM TestCases
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R+1 R, Rec, CASE
        WHEN PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Expr)>0 THEN STUFF(Expr, PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Expr), 7, '')
        WHEN PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Expr)>0 THEN STUFF(Expr, PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Expr), 6, '')
        WHEN PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9]%', Expr)>0 THEN STUFF(Expr, PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9][0-9]%', Expr), 5, '')
        ELSE STUFF(Expr, PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9]%', Expr), 4, '') END
    FROM Cte
    WHERE PATINDEX('%\tr[0-9]%', Expr)>0
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Expr FROM Cte
ORDER BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rec ORDER BY R DESC))
```

It yields:

```
bla99bla-rock
blabla-blabla
NULL

SomeText
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try

declare @s varchar(Max)='blabla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680blabla'

While PatIndex('%\tr[0-9]%', @s) > 0
        Set @s = REPLACE(@s,SUBSTRING(@s,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@s),1),'')

set @s= REPLACE(@s,'\tr','')
select @s
```

Comment: It will delete too much sometimes .`'bla99bla\tr568\tr1136\tr1704\tr2272-\tr2840\tr3408\tr3976\tr4544\tr5112\tr5680blabla'`

Comment: Nice, but it really takes too much. I would like to remove only numbers, which are behind \tr

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code:

1. get CHARINDEX(1st String) starting from 0
2. get CHARINDEX(1st String) starting from last
3. STUFF(yourString, result of step1+1, result of step2, '')

Answer (score 0):

In my text editor I used the following Regex expression
Replace \tx[0-9]+
With nothing.

EDIT: Hmm, there seems a bug in this composition window. The expression above has **two backslashes** at the start as you see

[in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FpKx.jpg)

But only one appears in the post.

-- 
Terry, East Grinstead, UK